# is there a detailed derivation of pdf of multivariate normal from the variance version to the covariance version?

Tags: probability-distributions

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) gives this equation to compute the pdf of the multivariate normal in k dimensions

${\displaystyle f_{\mathbf {X} }(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{k})={\frac {\exp \left(-{\frac {1}{2}}({\mathbf {x} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }})^{\mathrm {T} }{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}({\mathbf {x} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }})\right)}{\sqrt {(2\pi )^{k}|{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}|}}}}$

Some other posts such as [this one](https://www.statlect.com/glossary/log-likelihood) uses this form

[image]

Is there a detailed mathematical derivation from the latter to the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is for  a general multivariate normal distribution and the second one is only for independent and identically distributed normal variables.